# How do I add request headers on requests to oxford dictionary api?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

I was writing a simple ASP.NET program to use OXFORD Dictionary API, I'm having doubt on how to add the request headers on the request.
This is how I was doing it

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

HttpWebRequest req = null;
public static string PrimeUrl = "https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com:443/api/v1/entries/en/";
public static string uri = PrimeUrl + "robot";
req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);         
req.Headers.Add("app_id", "72536848");
req.Headers.Add("app_key", "0b4ed44eefa341a4e5cc42ec");
req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
req.Accept = "application/json"; 

}
```

The above snippet of code is found to be having error, do anyone have any prior knowledge on working with Oxford dictionary api? if yes, please do help.

Comment: The error was on the lines 
req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);         
req.Headers.Add("app_id", "72536848");
req.Headers.Add("app_key", "0b4ed44eefa341a4e5cc42ec");
req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
req.Accept = "application/json";

Comment: Are you asking for a problem with your code or just how to consume the service?

Comment: I'm asking what might be the error on adding this request headers on my program

Comment: The code that you show does not actually perform the request. You need to add some code get the response. You need to add something like var response = req.GetResponse(). Also, when I tried to use the credentials that you supplied, I got an Authentication Failed error. I was able to create my own credentials and use those.

Comment: but the error I'm getting is variable req is not in context, so I'm not able to refer that variable even, what might be the problem?

Comment: Where are you getting the error? It it a compile time error or a run time error? it may be helpful if you edit your question to show the exact error message.